# Обращение к классу, имея только его название в str форме

Tags: python

Проблема: есть классы, пользователь вводит строку с названием одного из классов. Также во всех классах есть одинаковая функция. Так вот, нужно вызвать функцию из класса, название которого ввел пользователь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [14]: class A:
    ...:     @staticmethod
    ...:     def hello():
    ...:         return 'hello world'
    ...:

In [15]: class B:
    ...:     @staticmethod
    ...:     def hello():
    ...:         return 'hello python'
    ...:

In [16]: globals()[input('Class name: ')].hello()
Class name: A
Out[16]: 'hello world'
```

Comment: Сделайте строки разными для наглядности, а то при выводе всегда одна и та же строка.